# javafx Eclipse Mars install

Tags: eclipse, javafx, installation, eclipse-mars

I have just installed eclipse Mars (4.5) and I have a problem with one old JavaFx project. Before installing Mars, I was using Luna and got no problem with my JavaFx projects, now I have the following problem with one project, all the javafx code are underlined with a similar error:

Access restriction: The type 'LineChart' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')

I do not know what it means, I tried to refresh the project and reboot Eclipse but the errors do not disappear, I can run my application without any problem though. I have other JavaFx project but none got this error.

I am using the latest JDK 1.8 update 45.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing JavaFX SDK from the build path and adding it again. I don't understand why it did not work the first time.